# Set a CSS Class jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that can set email preferences.

Next to each email there is a "Yes/No" button (meaning is this person subscribed to this type of email).

If it is "Yes", the css class is set to bootstraps `success` class.

If it is "No", the css class is set to Boostrap's `danger` class.

I am trying to set it up so that when the user clicks this, it toggles the class and changes the `html` property of the button from "Yes" to "No" or vice-verse.

I use `$(this).html("Yes");` and this works just fine.

However when changing the classes, I have a script that runs as:

```
$(this).removeClass("success");  
$(this).addClass("danger");
```

The problem is that when I use `$(this).removeClass()` and also `$(this).addClass()`, it doesn't change the element style. However, when I query the element it DOES remove the class and does add the class I want - the only problem is that the styling does not change.

The style DOES exist in the browser. If I load an element with `class="danger"` or an element with a `class="success"` it renders exactly how it should.

So something with this `removeClass` and `addClass` is not somehow triggering the STYLE to update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use browser developer tool (F12) and check whether CSS/styles files are properly embedded in the page.

Comment: If the class is being added/removed... the error is in the CSS, not jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, the jQuery is running fine. The style class does exist in the browser. When I load the page with SUCCESS or DANGER as the default class, both render fine. It is only when I change  it with the $(this).addClass() or $(this).removeClass()

Comment: Then there are cascading issues and the `danger`/`success` classes are being overridden due to hierarchy in the CSS.

Comment: Use the Style sidebar to see what styles are being assigned to the element and which CSS rules they're coming from. Then you can make your selector more specific to override it.

Comment: When you use `addClass()`, it doesn't remove any other classes, and those may be taking precedence. The Style sidebar in the DOM viewer will show you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works just fine for me,

*however, without your exact HTML and Javascript, this is simply a guess*

Let me know how it goes for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.email-button').on('click',function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('btn-danger btn-success');
      $(this).html($(this).hasClass('btn-success') ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-danger email-button">No</button>
```

Comment: That worked perfect. In looking over docs, I cannot see why the toggleClass would work when the removeClass and the addClass dont do the same. The only thing I can think of is that the toggleClass maybe LOADS the classes and their styles when the page renders. And then just toggles between them.... I guess? If anybody can clarify that, that would be appreciated